# How to make zsh completion show the first guess on the same line (like fish's)?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, fish

In Fish when you start typing, autocompletion automatically shows the first autocompleted guess on the line itself.

In zsh you have to hit tab, and it shows the autocompletion below. Is there anyway to make zsh behave more like fish in this regard?

(I am using [Oh My Zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)...)

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/tarruda/zsh-autosuggestions

Comment: Yes! That's awesome! You should write it up as an answer so people will see it.

Comment: I'm still fixing bugs, once its 100% ready for daily usage I will

Comment: Follow the steps here to get other features as well:
https://github.com/abhigenie92/zsh_to_fish

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I have implemented a [zsh-autosuggestions](https://github.com/tarruda/zsh-autosuggestions) plugin.

It should integrate nicely with [zsh-history-substring-search](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search) and [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting) which are features ported from fish.

Comment: Highlighting with this doesn't work for me and a number of others and issues on the github don't seem to be addressed. See https://github.com/tarruda/zsh-autosuggestions/issues/12

Comment: @Eli This plugin has recently been rewritten to address many of the issues. Feel free to give it another shot.

Comment: Here's the thing about zsh-autosuggestions, it cues off of history which is often similar in effect as tab-completion, but it's entirely different. I think what many of us are looking for is for the exact value that tab would complete to be shown, instead. This is a very significant distinction...

Comment: @StevenLu Tab-completion suggestions have been implemented on a feature branch. Take another look: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/pull/330

Answer (score 28):

Try:

```
autoload predict-on
predict-on
```

See:

```
info zsh --index-search=predict-on
```

for details.

Comment: This is technically the correct answer. However, the zsh predict support is rather abysmal compared to fish as it currently stands (at least with the configurations I tested.)

Comment: How do you turn it off?

Comment: I don't like this at all.

Answer (score 11):

Follow the steps here to get other features as well:
https://github.com/abhigenie92/zsh_to_fish

1. Install oh-my-zsh

```
sh -c "$(wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh -O -)"
```

2. Clone necessary plugins.

```
git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/zsh-autosuggestions
git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-~/.oh-my-zsh/custom}/plugins/zsh-history-substring-search
git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting.git ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-~/.oh-my-zsh/custom}/plugins/zsh-syntax-highlighting
```

3. Add plugins to `~/.zshrc` as

```
plugins = ( [plugins...] zsh-autosuggestions zsh-history-substring-search zsh-syntax-highlighting)
```

Note: make sure `zsh-syntax-highlighting` is the last one in the above list.

4. Fix background theme issues (Not necessary depends on your theme.)
   Add the following line to your `~/.zshrc`.

```
ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_HIGHLIGHT_STYLE='fg=white'
```

5. Restart zsh

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

If you like the answer, please consider starring the github repo.