# Zsh disable autofill

Tags: shell, zsh, interactive

Zsh disable autofill

If I open a terminal and enter:

```
echo 'hello world'
```

after that if i press `e` it "suggests" the previous command. How can I disable
this? I tried this with no success:

```
autoload predict-on
predict-on
predict-off
```

I am using stock Manjaro from here
https://osdn.net/projects/manjaro/storage/xfce

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command line prediction](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56281/command-line-prediction) and reverse of [How to make zsh completion show the first guess on the same line (like fish's)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84844/72456)

Comment: run `autoload predict-off && predict-off`

Comment: This is not the default behavior. Post your `.zshrc`.

Comment: Then please edit your question to say so, and also to point to the default zsh configuration on Manjaro. Because this is not the default behavior of zsh itself.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using zsh as a login shell. There's no reason why a login shell should be POSIX-compliant. There's also no reason to change distributions based on the default login shell, since it's trivial to change your login shell.

Comment: @Gilles I highly respect your contribution on this site, but frankly you are wrong on all accounts. Any **default** login shell should be POSIX compliant so that users dont have to learn 10 different shells. Zsh should be non default so that people can switch if they choose. Its a good reason to boycott a distro because we should support homogeneity among default login shells